# Задача на комбинированный тип. Pascal

Tags: pascalabc.net, ряды

Написать программу на Паскале. 
Описать тип комплексных чисел `type complex = record re, im: real end;`
Ввести комплексное число в переменную z типа complex, вычислить и вывести значение экспоненты exp(z) от введённого числа z (в виде двух вещественных чисел), используя ряд Тейлора:

```
exp(z) = 1 + z + (z^2)/2! + (z^3)/3! + ... + (z^n)/n! + ...
```

Вычисления следует завершать, когда очередной член суммы по абсолютной величине меньше константы со значением 10^(-6).

```
const eps = 0.000001;
type complex = record re, im: real end;
var z, a, e: complex;
    n, i: integer;
begin
  readln(z.re);
  readln(z.im);
  e.re := 1;
  e.im := 1;
  a := z;
  i := 1;
  n := 1;
  while abs(a.re * a.re + a.im * a.im) >= eps * eps do
    begin
      e.re := e.re + (a.re / n);
      e.im := e.im + (a.im / n);
      a.re := (a.re * z.re - a.im * z.im);
      a.im := (a.im * z.re + a.re * z.im);
      inc(i);
      n := n * i;
    end;
  writeln(e.re);
  writeln(e.im);
end.
```

Тестирующая система выдает runtime error. Помогите найти ошибку.

Comment: попробуйте ещё `const eps` задать тип. Ну и да, n тоже сделайте дробным. оно может переполнится (и ооочень быстро)

Comment: @pavel, не помогло. Может с делением какая-то беда?

Comment: а какая версия компилятора?

Comment: код ошибки известен? возможно числа вводятся не в том формате

Comment: @pavel, судя по всему именно оно и переполняется. Учитывая, что это факториал :)

Comment: @Grundy, Runtime error 201

Comment: [201 Range check error
If you compiled your program with range checking on, then you can get this error in the following cases:
An array was accessed with an index outside its declared range.
Trying to assign a value to a variable outside its range (for instance an enumerated type).](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html)

Comment: с freepascal правда, но думаю смысл примерно один :-) попробуй заменить тип у n на extended